# How to configure sw-precache-webpack-plugin to cache custom paths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, sw-precache

I have created a react app with create-react-app and ejected it.
`service-worker.js` is looking for `/index.html`, `/static/js/main.js` and `/static/css/main.css` to cache. I want to configure it to look for `/index.html`, `/js/main.js` and `/js/main.css` without changing their output directory.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to know is that `sw-precache` does not actually include your source code. What they do is they generate a list of files that they will retrieve and store in a cache as soon as they are installed.

That said if you have ejected I would recommend you upgrade to the latest version which is now called Workbox. (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/get-started/webpack)

The way I always use it is to have it scan a directory for particular file types and include those. So if I ever add an image to a directory it will be included in the new service-worker.
You can have it set to scan your build folder.

```
new workboxPlugin({
  globDirectory: path.resolve('build'),
  globPatterns: ['**/*.{html,js,css,png,svg}'],
  swDest: path.resolve('dist', 'sw.js'),
}),
```

For other options (such as ignoring large files, not refreshing hashed assets etc you can look at the configuration documentation here:
(https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-build#.Configuration)

Comment: Echoing this, I no longer maintain sw-precache-webpack-plugin and you should use the supported workbox plugin.